# Forbidden page when submit a form with an url

Tags: html, forms, url

few days ago i've changed host for my site, and now on the new server i have a strange error, when i submit a form with method get and an input text field with an url inside the server seem unable to find page.

here is where i'm testing it

http://www.oscurodrago.it/tools/testserver.php

that is an exemple of the error generated 404 forbidden page

http://www.oscurodrago.it/tools/testserver.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fexemple.com

and that is url w/o an url

http://www.oscurodrago.it/tools/testserver.php?u=test

do you know why it dosen't work?

Comment: It's actually a 403 forbidden. The 404 hint only means the server can't deliver a proper 403-error-page because it can't find any (and therefore returns an additional 404).

Comment: ok is 403 error but how is possible? the page is forbidden when a params have an url?

Comment: I guess it's due to some mod_security settings on your apache which recognizes the URL as invalid, because it contain's invalid characters. I'm not sure if your form does escape them correctly before posting, so I'd suggest using POST instead (if that's an option).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it's due to some mod_security settings on your host. They most likely don't like URLs being passed as parameters (it's a possible cross-site-scripting vulnerability).

So you could either ask your host to not be so strict (which he won't do, I guess) or try submitting the form with POST instead of GET.

Answer (score 0):

you might wanna check the the CHMOD of the file is 644, this is something most servers require as security, especially when running SuExec or SuPHP.